# Android - Firebase Analytics in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, google-analytics, admob

I was implementing **Admob** in one of my fragments and when I reached the part where I should integrate **Firebase Analytics** I got an error with this line :

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

now I am certain that the problem is with the `(this)` part in particular, I tried several solutions but I didn't manage to fix it

**what I tried**

I tried replacing `(this)` with `getActivity().getContext()` and `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

**ERROR**

```
Error:(91, 60) error: incompatible types: OneFragment cannot be converted to Context
//One fragment is the name of the fragment
```

Comment: And what was that error?

Comment: `Error:(91, 60) error: incompatible types: OneFragment cannot be converted to Context`  `//where OneFragment is the class name of my fragment`

Comment: what is import statment for fragment in your class? try changing it to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: @AmodGokhale it is already set to that

Comment: can you share your code of fragment class? try to debug and see if getactivity() is giving you null pointer? try to override public void onAttach(Activity activity) to get activity inside fragment.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

with

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getContext());
```

Comment: where do you need to put this line? in `onCreate`, `onCreateView` or in `onActivityCreated`

Comment: @JelmerBrands onAttach

Answer (score 0):

Override the onAttach for the Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just copy the following code to your fragment class.

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
//write others needed function 

private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getContext());

}

}
```

Comment: why use "getContext()" and not the "context" that is provided as parameter of the onAttach function?